# Поисковики

Tags: поиск

Как сделать чтоб твой сайт можно было бы найти через поисковик

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В первую очередь желательно разместить файл [robots.txt](http://robots.txt) в корне сайта, со следующим содержанием:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow:
```

В этом примере поисковым роботам разрешается индексация всего сайта.

[Здесь](http://robotstxt.org.ru/robotsexclusion/guide) очень понятно описан этот процесс.

Answer (score 0):

- [Google](https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/submit-url)
- [Yandex / Rambler](http://webmaster.yandex.com/addurl.xml)
- [Yahoo](http://search.yahoo.com/info/submit.html)
- [Апорт](http://catalog.aport.ru/rus/add/AddUrl.aspx)
- [Bing](https://ssl.bing.com/webmaster/legacy/submitsitepage.aspx)
- [Mail.ru / GoGo](http://go.mail.ru/addurl)
- [Нигма](http://www.nigma.ru/index_menu.php?action=click_menu&menu_element=add_site)
- [Мета](http://web.meta.ua/?action=add)